# calculate mean median and standard deviation returns string

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python. I want to calculate the sum, mean, median and standard deviation of each column but it returns a long string as the answer

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
  'apple': {
    0: '15.8', 
    1: '3562', 
    2: '51.36', 
    3: '179868', 
    4: '6.0', 
    5: ''
  },
  'banana': {
    0: '27.84883300816733',
    1: '44.64197389840307',
    2: '',
    3: '13.3',
    4: '17.6',
    5: '6.1'
  },
  'cheese': {
    0: '27.68303400840678',
    1: '39.93121897299962',
    2: '',
    3: '9.4',
    4: '7.2',
    5: '6.0'},
  'egg': {0: '',
    1: '7.2',
    2: '66.0',
    3: '23.77814972104277',
    4: '23967',
    5: ''}
  }
)
```

For example, to calculate sum of apple column, I used
`df['apple'].sum()` it gives me an output of `15.8356251.361798686.0` which is strange.

Kindly help.

Comment: You need to store your values as floats, not strings. You will note that the sum is just the concatenated strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want to do:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
df.describe()

                   apple     banana     cheese           egg
    count       5.000000   5.000000   5.000000      4.000000
    mean    36700.632000  21.898161  18.042851   6015.994537
    std     80047.651817  14.955567  15.077552  11967.362577
    min         6.000000   6.100000   6.000000      7.200000
    25%        15.800000  13.300000   7.200000     19.633612
    50%        51.360000  17.600000   9.400000     44.889075
    75%      3562.000000  27.848833  27.683034   6041.250000
    max    179868.000000  44.641974  39.931219  23967.000000

df.sum()

    apple     183503.160000
    banana       109.490807
    cheese        90.214253
    egg        24063.978150
    dtype: float64
```

Comment: The codes suggested by Nathaniel worked. Thanks a lot